# GridBagLayout goes crazy

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a GridBagLayout, but one label (maxSizeLbl) goes crazy and an other one (maxDateLbl) isnt visible, anyone knows what I've done wrong?

Here is the Picture:

[image]

And here is the Code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class SearchGUI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Search Files");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField rootTF = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField containsTF = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField containsNotTF = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField minSizeTF = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField maxSizeTF = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField  suffixTF = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField  prefixTF= new JTextField(10);
        JTextField minDateTF = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField maxDateTF = new JTextField(10);
        JCheckBox hiddenCB = new JCheckBox("search hidden");
        JCheckBox recursiveCB = new JCheckBox("search subfolders");
        JButton searchBtn = new JButton("search");
        JLabel rootLbl = new JLabel("search in: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel containsLbl = new JLabel("Filename contains: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel containsNotLbl = new JLabel(" Filename contains not", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel minSizeLbl = new JLabel("min. Size", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel maxSizeLbl = new JLabel("max. Size", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel suffixLbl = new JLabel("Filetypes", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel prefixLbl = new JLabel("begins with", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel minDateLbl = new JLabel("min. Date", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel maxDateLbl = new JLabel("max Date", JLabel.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        c.setLayout(gbl);


//      addComponent(c, gbl, );
        //                                                              x  y  w  h  wx   wy
        addComponent(c, gbl,                rootLbl, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,                 rootTF, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,         containsLbl, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,          containsTF, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,    containsNotLbl, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,     containsNotTF, 0, 5, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,           minSizeLbl, 0, 6, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,          maxSizeLbl, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,            minSizeTF, 0, 7, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,           maxSizeTF, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,                suffixLbl, 0, 8, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,                 suffixTF, 0, 9, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,            minDateLbl, 0, 10, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,            maxSizeLbl, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,             minDateTF, 0, 11, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,            maxDateTF, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
        addComponent(c, gbl,                searchBtn, 0, 12, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

        frame.setSize(gbl.preferredLayoutSize(c));
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    static void addComponent( Container cont, 
            GridBagLayout gbl, 
            Component c, 
            int x, int y, 
            int width, int height, 
            double weightx, double weighty ) 
    { 
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(); 
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
                gbc.gridx = x; gbc.gridy = y; 
                gbc.gridwidth = width; gbc.gridheight = height; 
                gbc.weightx = weightx; gbc.weighty = weighty; 
                gbl.setConstraints( c, gbc ); 
                cont.add( c ); 
    } 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You added the **maxSizeLbl** twice (instead of **maxDateLbl**)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you thoroughly study the indispensable `GridBagLayout` tutorial at http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/ first.

It seems like you don't use any IDE. Eclipse shows a curious yellow squiggly line below `maxDateLbl`--it's not being used. And if you click on `maxSizeLbl`, you'll see it's being used twice.

Replace the second `maxSizeLbl` with `maxDateLbl`.

And watch the tutorial again.

Answer (score 2):

Including Geoffrey's discovery about maxSizeLbl/maxDateLbl, this is what worked for me and assumes the field labels occupy the left side of the text field and not the top. (Only the relevant section of code shown.)

```
addComponent(c, gbl,        rootLbl, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,         rootTF, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl,    containsLbl, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,     containsTF, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl, containsNotLbl, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,  containsNotTF, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl,     minSizeLbl, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,      minSizeTF, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,     maxSizeLbl, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,      maxSizeTF, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl,      suffixLbl, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,       suffixTF, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl,     minDateLbl, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,      minDateTF, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,     maxDateLbl, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
addComponent(c, gbl,      maxDateTF, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0);

addComponent(c, gbl,      searchBtn, 0, 6, 4, 1, 1.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: I forgot to add that you may want to want to use "frame.pack();" as a replacement for the "frame.setSize(gbl.preferredLayoutSize(c));" statement, otherwise some of the viewport is clipped.